# Partially changing background color of a <View> component in React Native based on %

Tags: css, react-native

So I have these Views in react native I am using as cards, and I want to partially change the background of the view based on a %

[image]

So for example I would find what % 230 is of 1000 and I would fill the background of the card that % to a different color. Anyone have any suggestions on doing the background color with a % like that? I know I can fill it with border and border width but the issue is that pushes the content out of the way to fill it. I need the content to stay in place but the background color change partially based on the %. I also tried making another View overtop of this one and adding the border and border width and filling the top one, but that covers the content of the bottom one, which doesnt really help either.

Not sure a code snippet is needed for this question but screw it:

```
 <View key={value.title + index} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', margin: 10, borderRadius: 5, width: '90%', height: 70, alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <View style={{ margin: 15 }}>
                                <IconX
                                    size={30}
                                    origin={ICON_TYPE.FONT_AWESOME5}
                                    name={'piggy-bank'}
                                    color={'black'}
                                />
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', width: 125 }}>
                                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{value.title}</Text>
                                {value.date && (
                                    <Text>{value.date.toDateString()}</Text>
                                )}
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', marginLeft: '-5%' }}>
                                <View style={{ width: 150 }}>
                                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'right', color: '#F36A53' }}> ${value.currentAmount} / ${value.goalAmount}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding another card overtop of it and just using a transparent border color so it didnt cover the content, but I am not totally happy with this solution, so am open to any other answers. Thanks.